# Reload the list when something is changed in Pagination JavaFX without changing the page

Tags: java, javafx

Sorry for the misunderstanding and lack of explanations. I edited my question.

I have the main where i just start the 2 windows, this pages and a button that adds 5 to the list.

```java
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Service service = new Service();
        service.setNumbers(new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)));
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("page.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 500, 500);
        fxmlLoader.<PageController>getController().setService(service);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        Stage stage1 = new Stage();
        var button = new Button();
        button.setText("Add 5");
        button.setOnAction(event -> service.addNumber(5));
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(button, 20, 30);
        stage1.setScene(scene1);
        stage1.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

The Service has a list of Integers and a PropertyChangeSuport object that fires a property change when a new number was added to the list.

```java
public class Service {

    private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    public List<Integer> integerList;

    public void addListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        this.propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void setNumbers(List<Integer> numbers) {
        this.integerList = numbers;
    }

    public void addNumber(Integer number) {
        integerList.add(number);
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("Added a number.", null, number);
    }
}
```

The page controller creates pages with 2 elements on each and it's an Observer to the Service.

```java
public class PageController implements PropertyChangeListener {

    @FXML
    private Pagination pagination;
    private Service service;

    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
        this.service.addListener(this);
        reloadList();
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        reloadList();
    }

    private void reloadList() {
        pagination.setPageCount(service.integerList.size() / 2 + service.integerList.size() % 2);
        pagination.setPageFactory(this::createPage);
    }

    private VBox createPage(int pageIndex) {
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        var min = pageIndex * 2;
        var max = Math.min(pageIndex * 2 + 2, service.integerList.size());
        var list = service.integerList.subList(min, max);
        list.forEach( item -> {
            var link = new Hyperlink(item.toString());
            vbox.getChildren().add(link);
        });
        return vbox;
    }
}
```

My propblem is that when I press the "Add five" button the page returns to 0 because of the "realoadList" function and i want it to remain on the same page. I've tried with the `pagination.setCurrentPageIndex` but the animation ruins it. How can I keep the list up to date without going back to the page 0?

This is the page.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Pagination?>


<Pagination fx:id="pagination" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.stackoverflow.PageController" />
```

Comment: [mcve] please (vs. near-pseudo-code snippets) .. that said: I don't think there's a way to stop the animated transition - it's coded deep down in private code of PaginationSkin. But then, this looks a bit of an xy-problem: why to you reset the factory if you seem to want to reload the current page?

Comment: I've edited my question, I hope it's easier to understand now. Thank you and I'm sorry for the lack of explanations.

Comment: I want to reload all the pages when something it's changed.

Comment: @kleopatra It seems, from my testing using JavaFX 17.0.1, that for whatever reason, updating the `pageCount` property causes the `Pagination` to jump back to the first page. Otherwise, I would suggest to the OP to simply keep a reference to the current page and update its content as needed. Though that may work if the size of the backing data does not change in such a way as to cause the page count to change.

Comment: @Slaw keeping a reference to the current page and resetting was the scenario before the edit - which was clarifying and changing the problem at the same time ;)

Comment: @kleopatra this would work if I could change the page index without the animation.

Comment: Well, there should be no need to reset the `pageFactory`. Each page is a `Node`. If you keep a reference to the `Node` (or whatever specific subtype you're using), then you can simply update its contents when the items on the page are updated (either directly or because items were added/removed from previous pages). But then the fact it jumps to page 1 when the page count is updated, which makes no sense in my opinion, seems to mess everything up. And unfortunately, it doesn't look like you can legitimately stop a `Pagination` from animating unless you're willing to create your own skin.

Comment: I would honestly consider submitting a bug report for unexpected behavior. Like I said, in my testing, simply _adding_ more items to a list, which caused the page count to update, would cause the `Pagination` to jump to page 1 (page index 0). There is no reason, that I can think of, for that to happen. The page index should not change unless changing the page count would cause the page index to be out of range. What do you think, @kleopatra ?

Comment: @Slaw agree :) but here resetting the factory  looks like the culprit ... don't if just the content of a page changes (btw: not near an IDE for a couple of days .. )